# Defining a struct member with private module types

Tags: rust

I've been using a bunch of modules that have a build() function which returns a struct. However, when I try to create my own "super" struct to bundle them together, I run into the error `` module `xxx` is private  rustc(E0603) ``. If there is a trait I can pass the individual variable as a parameter but cannot figure out how to define/box it up for a struct.

The current example of this I'm hitting is when creating a hyper client.

```
// Error due to privacy and cannot use the trait to define the member type
// Both the "hyper_rustls::connector" and "hyper::client::connect::http" modules are private.
struct SecureClient {
    client: hyper::client::Client<
                hyper_rustls::connector::HttpsConnector<hyper::client::connect::http::HttpConnector>> 
}

// Works, but passing the client everywhere as an individual variable is not realistic.
fn use_client(client: hyper::client::Client<impl hyper::client::connect::Connect>) -> () {
    ()
}

let https_conn = hyper_rustls::HttpsConnector::new(4);
let client: hyper::client::Client<_, hyper::Body> = hyper::Client::builder().build(https_conn);
```

Being newish to Rust, I'm struggling to figure out what the proper jargon is for what I'm trying to do, let alone make it work. Links to any docs or code examples about this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but you can use the public re-export `hyper_rustls::HttpsConnector` instead of the private `hyper_rustls::connector::HttpsConnector` and the public re-export `hyper::client::HttpConnector` instead of the private `hyper::client::connect::http::HttpConnector`.
You can read about re-exports here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#re-exporting-names-with-pub-use

Comment: Thanks, changing that worked, I didn't think to look into the re-exports. I was using the IDE to get the type returned by the instantiation, which shows the private types instead of the public alias.